# How can I tell if I've set up Google Analytics Ecommerce correctly?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

How can I tell if I've set up Google Analytics Ecommerce correctly?

In the documentation, Google gives a very clear example with their Universal Analytics that illustrates how to "require" the ecommerce code, create a transaction, add items, and then send the result to Google.

I have carefully followed these instructions, and everything on the Ecommerce tab of Google Analytics reads zero.  I thought that perhaps, like the other tabs, the data is updated on a daily basis and I would need to use one of the tabs in the "Real Time" section.

No dice - I don't see any indication that the data was received.  I clearly spelled out a purchase ID to be sent to Google Analytics and I don't see it anywhere.

I've made an educated guess that perhaps the "Conversions" tab under Real Time is where I should see my data, but I don't know.

It's quite striking that Google gives such clear and articulate instructions about setting up Google Analytics, but no clear instructions about testing it.  Here is the link with the instructions I'm talking about: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en

**Edit:** I can now see that the Ecommerce tabs shows the transactions for yesterday, but I can't see any way to get real time Ecommerce data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of browser plugins that can help you debug stuff a little more quickly than waiting for the data to show up in GA - I'd recommend either the Google Analytics Debugger, or the Observepoint debugger (both available in the Chrome webstore). If you see products, orders, etc. not getting set properly, you can at least cut the feedback time.

Assuming everything is implemented correctly, is it possible you have IP filters set up in GA? This would preclude any data from those IP addresses appearing.

Comment: Other features of Google Analytics work fine, so I'm certain that it's not getting filtered.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the plugins that Tom mentioned, you can also do the following:

1. Point to the debug JS file. This will output info about the pings to your console. For UA code, change the reference from `/analytics.js` to `/u/analytics_debug.js`.
2. Check your net tab within your developer tools to see if the ping to Google's server is getting sent or not.

If none of that works, please edit to include your code. That always helps ;)